# Por que no funciona mi group by de eloquent?

Tags: laravel, sql

No consigo hacer que funciona el group by de laravel ya sea con eloquent o con query builder, he puesto los siguientes codigos:

Query Builder:

```
$amortizaciones = DB::table('amortizacion')
                        ->select('amortizacion.*')
                        ->groupBy('id_fac_enc')
                        ->get();
```

Eloquent:

```
$amortizaciones = App\Amortizaciones::all()->groupBy('id_fac_enc');
```

pero de ninguna forma logro hacer que funcione, en el código con **query builder** ya no me da error cuando le coloco todos los campos en el `groupby` (hasta los de `created_at` y `updated_at`) pero no es lo que yo quiero porque me los da todos y no los quiero así, cual podría ser la solución?

estoy utilizando laravel 5.8

Comment: Ya lo solucione, gracias, encontre otro metodo el cual conservo mi query, ya que de forma similar lo hice en mysql

Comment: Pasare el link donde encontre la solucion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqV9wfu5gZs

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta debe ser de este modo:

**Caso 1**

```
$amortizaciones = App\Amortizaciones::select('columna1', 'columna2')
                                    ->groupBy('columna1', 'columna2')
                                    ->get();
```

Observaciones:

- Necesitas indicar que columnas vas a recuperar en tu consulta
- Tu método `groupBy()` necesita recibir las mismas columnas *por su nombre* que estés seleccionando
- Sustituye el método `all()` por el método `select()` en el cual indicas las columnas que vas a recuperar

**Caso 2**

O bien si quieres conservar el método `all()` deberás indicarle que columnas requieres recuperar de este modo y agrupar por las mismas:

```
$amortizaciones = App\Amortizaciones::all('columna1', 'columna2')
                                    ->groupBy('columna1', 'columna2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estas intentando agrupar. Recuerda que todos los campos tienen que pasar por una función de agregación.

```
SELECT id FROM users GROUP BY id
```

En esta consulta agrupa los id´s pero ¿qué pasa cuando agrego otro campo por el cual no quiero que se haga la agrupación?.

```
SELECT id, MAX(email) as email FROM users GROUP BY id
```

La función `MAX`, `CONCAT`, `MIN`, ETC. Son funciones que te ayudan agregar a las agrupaciones. Cuando utilizas **MySQL** con **MariaDB** este error es poco comun. Pero con bases de datos como **Postgres**, **SQL serve**, **Oracle**, Etc. Es común tener este tipo de errores.

Yo intentaría algo así tu consulta.

```
\DB::select(
     "SELECT i
       d_fac_enc, 
       MAX(columA) ascolumA, 
       MAX(columB) as columB, 
       MAX(columETC) as columETC  
     FROM amortizacion 
     GROUP BY id_fac_enc");
```